# spring environment.getProperty value exist but @value not found

Tags: spring, spring-boot

In version 2.5.4 of springboot, `environment` the Environment returns a normal value. By the way, in @Value, the value is returned as the key value.
What settings are missing? or am I using it wrong?

```
|-core
|   |- com.example.core
|   |             |- CoreConfiguration.class
|   |-resources
|          |-application.yml
|
|- module
|   |- com.example.module
|   |             |- Applicatin.class
|   |
|   |-resources
|        |- application.yaml
```

CoreConfiguration

```java
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.example.core"},
    useDefaultFilters = false,
    includeFilters = {
        @ComponentScan.Filter(type = FilterType.ANNOTATION, value = Service.class),
        @ComponentScan.Filter(type = FilterType.ANNOTATION, value = Component.class),
        @ComponentScan.Filter(type = FilterType.ANNOTATION, value = Repository.class),
        @ComponentScan.Filter(type = FilterType.ANNOTATION, value = Configuration.class)
    })
@Configuration
public class CoreConfiguration {
}
```

Core application.yml

```yaml
spring:
  profiles:
    active: local
```

Application.class

```java
@SpringBootApplication(
    scanBasePackageClasses = {CoreConfiguration.class}, 
    scanBasePackages = "com.example.module")
public class Application {
```

module application.yaml

```
spring:
  messages:
   basename: messages/message
```

---

```
environment.getProperty("spring.messages.basename") // messages/message
```

```
@Value("${spring.messages.basename}")
String basename;  // value is ${spring.messages.basename}
```

Comment: Can you share additional details? Is that yaml your `application.yaml`? Any special configurations? Where is the `basename` variable declared? On the surface this should work.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @IdanElhalwani Sorry, added the necessary information. :)

Comment: Shouldn't `application.yaml` be located in the `resources` directory?

Comment: @knittl it is located the resources.

Comment: Something is off in the setup. Mind posting the project or a minimally reproducible version of it?